org-mode recurring habits: how do I force recurring events to happen in the next week on the same day?
I am using org-mode to track recurring tasks, however I am running into a problem when scheduling the subsequent instance of a recurring task. For some reason, the recurring task seems to get rescheduled for the following weekday, but it keeps showing up on my org-agenda calendar before the scheduled day.
For example, say I have a meeting every Thursday late afternoon. So I have a recurring task for this meeting in org-mode. Now I might finish this task on Thursday, but I might forget to mark the task complete until Friday. So I want the next instance of the task to occur on the following Thursday, no matter when the task was marked complete.
*** NEXT Late Meeting                        :Work:
SCHEDULED: <2024-09-19 Thur 17:00 +1w>
:PROPERTIES:
:REPEAT_TO_STATE: NEXT
:LOGGING: DONE(!)
:STYLE: habit
:Effort:   1:00
:END:
:LOGBOOK:
- State "DONE"       from "NEXT"       [2024-09-13 Fri 10:59]
- State "DONE"       from "NEXT"       [2024-09-05 Thu 18:49]

The problem is, that this task still shows up on my calendar on Friday and Saturday, even if I have marked it complete on Thursday.
Am I using the wrong operator with SCHEDULED: <2024-09-19 Thur 17:00 +1w> ? I know that some of those operator settings mean that the task should occur anytime before say 1 week. So I just wanted to make sure that the meeting task recurs on the appropriate day, Thursday, of each week. I don't want to see it on non-Thursdays, since that just clusters my org-agenda.

SCHEDULED does not mean what you think it means: for a meeting you want a simple timestamp. See Deadlines and Scheduling in the manual, and in particular the indented paragraph that's marked Important.

Does this help?

@NickD Ah, I see. So I can make a simple timestamp, just purely <2024-09-19 Thur 17:00 +1w> without the DEADLINE or SCHEDULED, and that would work. Would it continue to repeat each week?

Yes - the repeater +1w will take care of that. I will close this question as a duplicate of the one I linked to.

@NickD okay excellent. I will try that. Yeah, I can close the question or delete it. No problem.
